# how to activate 'more' option on command prompt (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-prompt

My code dumps a hell amount of data on the command prompt. How do I activate the 'MORE' option for the output so that I see the output page by page? (MS Visual Studio)

For eg. Matlab has the command 'more on' to do the same!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Windows command prompt you can append `| more` to your command, e.g.,

```
dir | more
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "more option". As James said above, there is a "more" command that you can use to paginate output.

Answer (score 0):

Create wrapper functions around the output functions.  In these functions, track the number of newlines.  If the amount reaches a given limit, pause the screen by using `std::istream::ignore()`.

Otherwise, as others have stated, pipe the output to a paging application.